# iis 7 caching PDF files causing wrong attachments to be sent

Tags: iis-7, smtp

I've got a weird problem with my web server.

I have a page that creates a PDF file and a button to send that same file as an attachment in an email.

So I hit create, then press send, create, then press send. The file name & location on the server is the same, but the contents change.

The thing is it frequently ends up sending the previous version even though it's over-written and no longer exists on the server. If I wait 10-20 minutes then it usually sends the correct file.

If I view the file in the browser it shows the latest version, even though it stills sends the old one in emails.

So I think it must be some sort of caching issue, does anyone know what I should change in IIS that could fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling Output Caching in IIS 7. Refer [Configure IIS 7 Output Caching](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/710/configure-iis-7-output-caching/) and [Caching](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/caching). There is a small troubleshooting section at the end of the first link, please refer that as well.